# What is an easy way to add help pages to an iOS app?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, documentation

We have different forms of documentation for our desktop apps, but until now most iOS apps have been fairly self-explanatory so we've been able to get by with simple hint strings in settings etc.

But for a more complex app I'd like to be able to create a few HTML pages that look approximately like native iOS UI and are easy to maintain.

Dashcode has a browser template that seems to fit the bill, but it's terribly buggy under Lion. I could start from scratch using something like iUI, but I'm wondering if there isn't something readymade already out there that would fit the bill?

Requirements:
- One or possibly two levels of hierarchy
- Display short formatted text with images
- Preferably HTML so the documentation authors can create and format the content on their own without touching the dev side of things

Any ideas or tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use CSS formatted HTML pages that can either be included in the project or served from the web or actually both (you can do a check so see if the app has a connection to the server and if so serve them up from there or serve them from a local resource).

I personally think the Static Cell UITableView is the ultimate way to display those help options.  That and Storyboard were the two big favorites for me in iOS5.